# Presenting a UIViewController with background transparent in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

I am presenting a viewController with transparent background. But the components on that viewController is invisible when it is presented. A blank viewController is seen.I have given alpha value and black background color. 
This is my code when  i call the transparent viewController

```
if indexPath.row==0
{
   let modalViewController = PopUpViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

[image]

But there is a orange color UIView present on this Controller which is invisible Thanks in advance[image]
 [image]

Comment: please share the Attribute inspector of the orange view

Comment: @Mina i have added the required image. I am able to create transparent viewcontroller but that viewcontroller's components are not visible.

Comment: sure, i will update my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to present your second Viewcontroller, which has a transparent background, modally. with the following config:

[image]

and that's the result :

[image]

for those who may not familiar with Opacity: in the situation like this, for transparency,  it's better to use **Opacity** instead of **Alpha**

[image]

Comment: It is getting presented transparent but the components on the second viewController which has become transparent is not visible. This is what my question is.

Comment: why isnt it transparent ? the blue color should be transparent black color

Comment: It's a blue transparent controller on a white controller, and the buttons and text are for second controller

Comment: can you share both viewcontrollers design in storyboard?

Comment: it's so easy, you just have to **performSegue** in cell selection:  ```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToSecondController", sender: nil)
        }
    }```

set identifier for your segue in storyboard, and do the configs like the image and it will work fine. be careful, you have to drag a segue from first controller to the second controller, not from a tableview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148322/discussion-between-nish-and-mina).

Answer (score 1):

You can take two view one as outerView (Transparent black) and  innerView( OrangeView) , note that both view are in same hierarchy. (as in screen shot)

- Default View of viewController background color should be clearColor.
- OuterView should having transparent black background.
- On Segue presentation property in Attribute inspector of Segue should be Over Full Screen as shown in image.

[image]

it will show on running.

[image]